# Выполнение виртуальных методов в запечатанных классах

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil

Рихтер говорит:

> Встретив вызов виртуального метода в запечатанном типе, JIT-компилятор может сгенерировать более эффективный код, задействовав *невиртуальный вызов*. Это возможно потому, что у **запечатанного класса не может быть производных классов.**

Как факт того, что у запечатанного класса не может быть производных классов, даёт право на невиртуальный вызов?

К примеру, если запечатанный класс наследует класс, в котором определён виртуальный метод, и его не переопределяет, то происходит поиск ближайшего переопределения вверх по иерархии с последующим полиморфным вызовом.

Или, к примеру, если запечатанный класс даже переопределяет виртуальный метод. Как факт того, что от этого класса не может быть производных классов, позволяет вызывать этот виртуальный метод невиртуально (посредством `call`)?

Я ещё как-то могу понять, когда говорят о значимых типах, к примеру о структурах, что компилятор знает, что полиморфизм здесь невозможен, так как структура является значимым типом, а значимые типы не
могут применяться для другого типа в качестве базового и по-другому реализовывать виртуальный метод (так как нельзя унаследовать структуру).

Вот ещё кусок фразы:

> Компиляторы стремятся использовать команду `call` при вызове методов, определённых значимыми типами, поскольку они запечатаны. В этом случае полиморфизм невозможен даже для виртуальных методов, и вызов выполняется быстрее.

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class A");
    }
}
 
sealed class B : A
{
}

public static void Main()
{
    B ob=new B();
    //Вызов метода Show из базового класса А выполняется что ли неполиморфно т.к. класс B запечатан?
    ob.Show();
}
```

**Вопрос:** Как факт того, что класс не может выступать в качестве базового типа для других типов, позволяет компилятору (или JIT-компилятору) вызывать виртуальные методы невиртуально? Что нам это даёт? Мы же не освобождаем компилятор от поиска других ближайших реализаций этого метода вверх по иерархии?

Поиск по иерархии происходит снизу вверх. Как факт того, что ниже ничего не будет, даёт нам право вызывать виртуальные методы невиртуально?

Comment: callvirt не гарантирует, что вызов будет виртуальным (но это не точно). Компилятор заменяет callvirt на call только когда очевидно, что экземпляр - не null (вызов методов из object у структур), а так зачастую где попало кидает callvirt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите знать, что думает об этом Microsoft - вот [ссылка](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/jit/GuardedDevirtualization.md) почитать. А так, степень оптимизации девиртуализации сильно зависит от версии .NET. Чем новее, тем эффективнее реализована девиртуализация.

А вообще если речь про .NET 7 и новее, то Microsoft [пишут следующее](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance_improvements_in_net_7/#analyzers):

> But if the JIT can see that a virtual method is being invoked on a sealed type, it can devirtualize the call and potentially even inline it.

**Вольный перевод:** Если JIT видит, что виртуальный вызов происходит на запечатанном `sealed` классе, он может его девиртуализовать, или даже встроить в вызывающий код.

Comment: как факто того, что метод запечатан позволяет JIT девиртуализовать этот метод?

Comment: @Naydachy ну, во-первых так написано, во-вторых это можно проверить средствами декомпиляции, на то же sharplab.io например. Такие штуки, которые не влияют на поведение кода, а например влияют на производительность, зачастую не описываются в документации, а только упоминаются в блогах. Поэтому лучшее, что можно здесь сделать - это взглянуть на скомпилированный код своими глазами.

Comment: @Naydachy я посмотрел на вашем конкретном примере, вызов девиртуализуется, и даже если убрать `sealed`, всё равно девиртуализация работает.

Comment: мне не важно что происходит, почему sealed даёт право компилятору проделывать такие трюки. Sealed `запрещает другим классам наследовать от этого класса`. Как это ограничение на наследование позволяет компилятору вызывать методы невиртуально ?

Comment: Если я скажу тебе что класс является запечатанным, то что даст тебе эта информация, чтобы ты смог девиртуализовать методы?

Comment: @Naydachy я не ковырялся в исходниках JIT, что вижу, то и пишу. Очевидно, что девиртуализация вызова возможна, когда в таблице инвокации не может быть более одного метода, а вот какие анализаторы отвечают за определение данного факта и как работают, я не в курсе. Если нужна подробная теория девиртуализации, нажмите на первую ссылку в ответе и почитайте. Опять же, если тип не может иметь наследников, то куда метод виртуализовать то? Какого полиморфизма вы ожидаете от запечатанного типа? Задайтесь вопросом, а возможен ли полиморфизм на запечатанном классе?

Comment: [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ7EAICC6De6WxWcAzFgG4CWYwEAhgDakAsWAygBYD2A7gAoAlFiIlCaElNJIAnAIBEOBUIDcY4gF902jGmwAhEHjQSd6dAGcAps2sATUgiwBhLCCwGCFtLuxwkAHZvNABIRAR0UIlQ0LceACMsAF4sKGs+V2F1MNDEgDpufmyo3U0gA) в таком некуда что ли виртуализовать?

Comment: @Naydachy ну, а куда? Полиморфизма нет и быть не может в этом случае. Вы просто вызываете метод базового класса, никакой виртуализации нет. Уберите `virtual`, что поменяется? Ничего.

Comment: Понял, можешь напоследок привести пример с полиморфизмом(на sharplab) , когда виртуализация используется. Что в данном случает используется под понятием виртуализация?

Comment: @Naydachy а что его приводить, создаете виртуальный метод в базовом классе, создаете override метод в наследнике, в переменную типа базового класса кладете экземпляр наследника, вызываете метод. Если отработал метод наследника - виртуализация работает, полиморфизм в действии. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override

Comment: @Naydachy, вот простой [пример](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwDoBKBXAdsASygFN0BhAeygAcCAbYgJwGUmA3AgY2IgG4BYAFBC4AJiQBBIQG8hASADaAWWLAAFhQAmASRp0AFCvVbd1OgHlqhCrgjoAchW246BXG4DmASgC6QpAEoAMxIHIzA2GB0KAAsSMwaAO76Xv6BsoKBSAC+QrmZQgD0AFQQxFHEmsWFKOIAQkggkjJ5QiKoAGy1SAAqPMAtmYFoXXBxACIUCRSJdfoNAEZeSAC8AHxIC+jTyV4CgtlAA=) того, о чём говорится в цитате. Смотрите тело метода _Test.DoShowB_. Вызов виртуальный. Раскомментируйте _sealed_. Вызов девиртуализуется. Закомментируйте _NoInlining_, Вызов встраивается.

Comment: На этапе компиляции CLR знает объект какого типа создаётся и в какую переменную типа помещается ссылка на объект ? `B ob=new B()'. Известно что создаётся объект типа B и ссылка присваивается ссылочной переменной типа B? А тут известно тоже самое `A ob2=new B();`?

Comment: @Naydachy конечно знает, а как иначе, это же явно в коде написано.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую я объяснить, как сам понимаю.
Создадим следующие классы:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Show() => Console.WriteLine("A");
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Show() => Console.WriteLine("B");
}

class C : B
{
    public override void Show() => Console.WriteLine("C");
}

sealed class D : A
{
    public override void Show() => Console.WriteLine("D");
}
```

Рассмотрим такой код:

```
B b1 = new B();
B b2 = new C();
D d = new D();

b1.Show();
b2.Show();
d.Show();
```

Классы `B` и `D` - прямые потомки `A`. На этом основании можно решить, что вызовы их методов `Show` должны быть одинаковы.

Однако, у класса `B` могут быть потомки, поэтому в ссылке типа `B` может храниться как экземпляр `B`, так и экземпляр `C`. Неизвестно заранее, что там будет. Поэтому вызов будет виртуальным.

В ссылке `D` может быть только экземпляр `D`. Поэтому можно вызвать его метод напрямую.

Comment: Но Вы не привели в пример то, что в ссылку `A` также можно поместить экземпляр класса `D`, тогда тут нельзя дать однозначный ответ, какой метод должен быть вызван. Соответственно, вызов тоже будет виртуальным

Comment: @NaClnik - да, конечно, речь именно о различиях `B` и `D`.

Comment: Кстати интересно. На этапе компиляции в IL (в текущей версии .net) все три вызова виртуальные (`callvirt`), хотя вызов Show для D мог бы, кажется, уже быть девиртуализован (спецификация, по крайней мере, это разрешает: _"It is valid to call a virtual method using `call` (rather than `callvirt`)..."_). Далее JIT девиртуализует (и инлайнит) все три вызова. То есть он знает, в том числе, что в b2 находится тип C (потому, видимо, что используются локальные переменные).